# Input type=button as if it were type=submit

Tags: javascript, button, input, dom-events

I need to have two inputs with a **different types**:

```
<input  type="button"  **onclick = "?????"**   name="back"  value="&#8592 Back"  >
<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Forward &#8594"  >
```

How can I do for type=button run this PHP code:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['back']))
    {

        $_SESSION['onpage'] = $_SESSION['onpage'] - 1;

        $query_questionset = "
        select Q.Constructor AS Constructor,
        QS.QuestionIDFKPK AS QuestionIDFKPK,
        Q.QuestionValue AS QuestionValue,
        QS.SortOrder AS SortOrder,
        QS.onpage AS onpage
        from tbluserset AS US
        inner join tblquestionset AS QS ON US.QuestionSetIDFKPK = QS.QuestionSetIDPK
        inner join tblquestion AS Q ON QS.QuestionIDFKPK = Q.QuestionIDPK
        where (US.UserIDFKPK = " . $UserId . ")
        and (US.UserSetIDPK= '" . $_SESSION['UserSetIDPK'] . "')
        and (QS.onpage = '" . $_SESSION['onpage'] . "')
        order by QS.SortOrder";

    }

    $QuestionSet_Constructors = mysql_query($query_questionset);
?>
```

My form and input submit works perfectly:

```
<form id= "formID"  class="formular"   method="post" action= "<?= $url = "QUESTIONAREnewdatabase.php"; ?>" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

What I need on `input type=button` for run that PHP code and the action form like if Back had `type=submit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way that uses Javascript, this will dynamically create and append a hidden input called `back` to the form, then submit the form - when the back button is clicked.

```
<script>
    function postBack()
    {
        var myForm = document.getElementById("formID");
        var backInput = document.createElement("input");
        backInput.type = "hidden";
        backInput.name = "back";
        backInput.value = "1";

        myForm.appendChild(backInput);
        myForm.submit();
    }
</script>


<input type="button" onclick="postBack()" name="back" value="&#8592 Back">
```

On the server side, you can now test for:

```
if(isset($_POST['back']))
{
    // back was pressed...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
< input type="submit" onclick = "?????" name="back" value="&#8592 Back" >
```

Comment: Can't be a submit this button :( , i need a diferent type.

Comment: if you use 'go back' are other form action

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" id="formID" class="formular" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Your inputs here -->
    <button type="submit" name="back">&#8592 Back</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Forward &#8594</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I can't use in that button type=submit and i need that run that php code. Dont mind if is a button or an input , the problem is that i cant use TYPE+SUBMIT for this .

Comment: I don't see why you can't use a submit button here? only the clicked button will be sent, even if both are of type=submit

Comment: because i'm checking if the user answer every fields of my form and this happen with a submit ( it's a js library) and if that happen with button Back the user can't go to page before without mark things on current page first.

Comment: might be worth adding that totally important point to your question unless you want another 3 useless answers, we aren't psychic :)